# Why can't I see buildings on my bing map?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, bing-maps

I can't understand why my bing map doesn't show buildings.
The ShowBuildings is True.

You can compare 2 screenshots and the difference is huge.
[First](http://firepic.org/images/2013-02/11/umpz0hxwb7te.png) -  Bing Maps for Windows Store appp (My app)
[Second](http://firepic.org/images/2013-02/11/sbp807nyfugb.png) - Native Bing Maps inside Windows 8 Pro

My xaml is pretty simple.

```
<MapsCore:Map x:Name="PART_Map"
                      Credentials="STRING_KEY"
                      ShowBuildings="True"
                      ShowBreadcrumb="True"
                      ShowNavigationBar="True"
                      />
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681884.aspx) website, some features of the Bing Maps API (like BirdsEye Imagery) are not available for public testing yet, and are only available through the [Extended Modes](https://connect.microsoft.com/silverlightmapcontrolctp) SDK. This may be where your problem is coming from.

Comment: I don't know nut I'm using official Bing Map SDK for Windows Store app from second link. So, it is useless use bing map in common case because I can't add needed geodate.